# how to compare pairwise elements of a CGPoint array to determine which has a greater x position

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of `CGPoint`s (which are arranged in a specific order) `[A1, A2,...,AN]`. How can I compare the elements in pairs of two to determine which has a greater x position? For example, comparing `A1.x` with `A2.x`, `A2.x` with `A3.x`, `A3.x` with `A4.x` and so on all the way to `AN.x` with `A1.x` (comparing elements in specific order).

Comment: `array.sort{$0.x > $1.x}`? Or what result do you expect?

Comment: @ShadowOf I believe the above will arrange the array in descending order of x values. What I am trying to achieve is a bit different from sorting. I want to be able to categorise the result of each pairwise comparison into two groups larger or smaller. For example,  `A1.x` larger `A2.x`, `A2.x` smaller `A3.x`, `A3.x` smaller `A4.x` and so on all the way to `AN.x` larger `A1.x`. Hence the array should remain unchanged.

Comment: You want to compare only nearby elements?

Comment: Yes, also the last and the first element.

Comment: I wrote generic solution, check it if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote extension function `pairwiseCompare(index: Self.Index?) -> Bool?`, that take index of element and compare this element with next (or with first, if it is last):

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == CGPoint {
    func pairwiseCompare(index: Self.Index?) -> Bool? {
        guard let index = index where startIndex.distanceTo(index) >= 0 && index.distanceTo(endIndex) > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        let secondIndex = index.successor() == endIndex ? startIndex : index.successor()
        return self[index].x > self[secondIndex].x
    }
    func pairwiseCompare() -> [Bool] {
        var result = [Bool]()
        for index in startIndex..<endIndex {
            result.append(pairwiseCompare(index)!)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 5, y: 1)]
print(array.pairwiseCompare(-1)) // nil
print(array.pairwiseCompare(0))  // Optional(false)
print(array.pairwiseCompare(1))  // Optional(false)
print(array.pairwiseCompare(2))  // Optional(true)
print(array.pairwiseCompare(3))  // nil

print(array.pairwiseCompare())   // [false, false, true]
```